# Python - How to get the date after entering a number between 1-365

Tags: python

How would you write a Python program that prompts a user for a year, a day of the year (an integer between 1 and either 365 or 366 to account for leap year), and gives the month, day and year?

Comment: Welcome to SO!
People will be more inclined to guide you if you can show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) to add a number of days to a starting date. Use `datetime.datetime` to create the starting date with January 1st of the year.